# Question about proof of Bézout's lemma

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[image: Picture of Proof (1)]

[image: Picture of Proof (2)]

Can someone please explain me why

$r=|a|-qd=|a|-q(|a|\bar{s}+bt)=|a|(1-q\bar{s})-bqt\in S\cup \{0\}$

?

Comment: Th. D1 which was applied here is the remainder Theorem which states that every pair of natural numbers (a,b) has exactly one pair of natural-numbers + 0 (q,r) such that a = qb+r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r $ is of the form  $xa+yb $ with  $x=\pm (1-q\bar{s})$ and  $y=-qt $. Hence  $r\in S\cup \{0\}$.

Comment: Okay I got it thanks a lot. r is positive or equal to zero by default therefore the linear combination must also be positive.